# Accessing hardware buttons within the camera app

Tags: java, android, plugins, camera

i wish to write a plugin that will enable me to access hardware buttons of the phone while using the camera app. how would i go about doing this. or is it even possible.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, you can't generally do this.  There are some keys that applications can respond to while in the background (specifically the media play/pause/etc buttons) but it is not generally possible to process key events while another app has focus.

Answer (score 0):

Your best best is to check the [Camera source](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Camera.git;a=tree) but you might consider making your own app based on Camera.

Comment: could i change the source and only send the updates to the camera app on the phone as some sort of plugin?

Comment: I don't believe you can update everyone's camera app like that, if the app support plugins users would download your library separately.  You could always contribute directly too.